# Get Application Info from package name

Tags: android

I have an application package name. Is there any way to get the icon, name of this application ?
package name example: com.example.name

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: yes. I found a method that returns all applications with all information. I need a method that returns a specific application information from its package name

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try something like:

```
    try {
        ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.example.name", 0);        

        Drawable icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app);
        String name = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(app);
        return icon;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "error in getting icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Will it work if the app with package "com.example.name" not install in the phone?

Comment: @Dharmendra It'll hit the `NameNotFoundException` catch block

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo) states that `getApplicationLabel` takes an `ApplicationInfo` argument. but you are feeding it a `String`

Answer (score 1):

```
String PackgeNameApp = "com.test.icon";
            String name="NULL";
            try
            {
                ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(PackgeNameApp, 0);
                Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(app);
                 name = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(app).toString();

            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                //
            }
```

Comment: How is this really any different than the answer that has already been accepted?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo) states that `getApplicationLabel` takes an `ApplicationInfo` argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable icon =getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("ur_package");

Strign label = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel("ur_package");
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo) states that `getApplicationLabel` takes an `ApplicationInfo` argument. but you are feeding it a `String`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get installed app package name then this code will be helpful to you.

```
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
                Log.i("InstalledAPK",pkgAppsList.toString());


              for(int i=0;i<pkgAppsList.size();i++){
                  list.add(pkgAppsList.get(i).toString());
                  Log.e("PACKAGENAME",""+MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(i).get(i).packageName);
              }


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```