# Android text share to application

Tags: android, android-intent

Good day everyone.
I am developing an application that can get text that are shared from the other applications.
My question is is it possible to get the application's name that shared the text to my application?

If there is a code sample or a link existing please share it with me.

Comment: Try getting the ComponentName from your Intent, then from the component get the package name and then from that check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417805/get-application-info-from-package-name