# getApplicationIcon() via PackageManager return a white bar image placed in the center that isn't the actual app icon

Tags: android, android-package-managers

after I invoke `getApplicationIcon()` like :

```
context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.cmcm.gamemaster");
```

it return this :

[image: white bar image]

a white bar image that placed in the middle. and always happen for specific application, the others in the installed application list never return the wrong icon.

before I invoke that method, I invoke **getPackageInfo()** about 30 times to build an installed application list. so I commented those codes then the problem gone.

I pay attention in the framework's source(android **6.0.1**) but not found any useful information.

have some guy encountered this problem before, or tell me the wrong icon's drawable file name in framework's source code so I can check what's happening.

thank in advance.

Comment: try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417881/6454463)

Comment: @RutvikBhatt not difference compare to before

Comment: Could you please share the loop that does the getPackageInfo call multiple times? I'm specifically curious if you're calling from multiple threads. PackageManager is a singleton instance, and it's not thread safe. Since you already said it works when you don't perform the other calls, chances are high that you actually call it from multiple threads at the same time, which would eventually end up in a race condition and override the icon buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description I assume you want to get a installed application list. Try this to get all applications:

```
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
...
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
...
```

And if you want for a particular one like in your code then try this:

```
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
...
ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.cmcm.gamemaster", 0);
Icon icon = app.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
...
```

You can get icon or title from `apps/app` since it contains all the info related to an app. Remember to use the **exact import statement**.

If the above methods doesn't work, refer [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/413hkm/list_view_with_all_the_installed_apps_and_their/). I'm sure that will be of use.

Comment: then **loadIcon(PackageManager)**? I tried, but not work

Comment: I changed the last code, please try accessing icon like in my code.

Comment: I did what you say before this comment, unfortunately it not work

Comment: I've added a link in my answer. In the 2nd comment on that thread, you'll see a code for creating a adapter with the app icon and name. Check it out. It's a well written code. I'm sure that will be of use to you :)

Comment: the only difference just take ApplicationInfo via PackageInfo, the problem still exists.

Answer (score -1):

getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("APP_PACKAGE_NAME") return Drawable. After getting drawable you can show icon in imageView using imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable).

TIPS:- Getting all installed app icon may hang your UI so you have to do this in a separate thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final Drawable drawable = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo.packageName);
                    ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: @VinceStyling Please try it once if you found any issue then please let me know.

Comment: I've done not any difference with your code before this question asking, I don't think your code can help.

Answer (score -1):

First get the PackageManager instance,

then pass the packageName in the getApplicationIcon(String) which will return the Bitmap!

```
PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
Bitmap mBitmap = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app.package.name);
holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(mBitmap);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers understand the problem even better.